# Is there any way to refactor this to be faster

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, refactoring, laravel-query-builder

```
   foreach ($events_id as $id) {
        $vis  = $visitors->where('event_id', $id);
        array_push($men, $vis->where('sex', 'male')->count());
        array_push($women, $vis->where('sex', 'female')->count());
        array_push($kids, $vis->where('sex', 'kids')->count());
    }
```

I have a collection of visitors and events IDs I want to check how many men - women - kids are in each event

it works but I want something faster

Answer (score 0):

In order to have greater performance it would be better to have integers instead of string to define the gender.

Also if you can modify your database query, it would be interesting to get these data directly through your query.

You can try like this :

```php
# App/Models/Event

{
    function male_visitors() {
        $this->belongsToMany(Visitor::class)->where('sex', 'male');
    }

    # Add each gender here
}
```

Your query can now look like this:

```php
Event::withCount(['male_visitors'])->get();
```

Comment: can you help me do it through query?

I have 10 events ids and I want to get how many men women kids are in each one

Comment: That is the cleanest way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done direct by your database query but I don`t know why you don't follow it.
But In this case we can only make fast by (if-else or swatch) condition.

IF-ELSE condition:

```
foreach ($events_id as $id) {
        $vis  = $visitors->where('event_id', $id);
        if($vis->sex == 'male'){
            array_push($men, $vis->count());

        }else if($vis->sex == 'female'){
            array_push($women, $vis->count());

        }else{
            array_push($kids, $vis->count());

    }
```

SWATCH condition:

```
foreach ($events_id as $id) {
        $vis  = $visitors->where('event_id', $id);
        switch ($vis->sex) {
            case 'male':
                array_push($men, $vis->count());
                break;
            case 'female':
               array_push($women, $vis->count());
                break;    
            
            default:
                array_push($kids, $vis->count());
                break;
        }
```

Comment: can you help me do it through query?

I have 10 events ids and I want to get how many men women kids are in each one

Comment: For that I need your model functions and table columns (events and visitors tables).

Answer (score 0):

You can group the result by sex, and then count how many rows are in each group.

```sql
SELECT sex, COUNT(sex) as count FROM test.test
WHERE event_id = 0
GROUP BY sex
;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK TRY THIS:

```
$male_count  = $visitors->whereIn('event_id', $events_id)->where('sex','male')->count();
    $female_count  = $visitors->whereIn('event_id', $events_id)->where('sex','female')->count();
    $kids_count  = $visitors->whereIn('event_id', $events_id)->where('sex','kids')->count();
```

It will work IA.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to use a query like this to get the count of men women and kids in each event

```
DB::table('visitors')
        ->select('visitors.sex', 'event_visitor.event_id', DB::raw('count(*) as num_visits'))
        ->join('event_visitor','visitors.id','=','event_visitor.visitor_id')
        ->whereIn('event_visitor.event_id',[1,2,3,4,5])
        ->groupBy('visitors.sex','event_visitor.event_id')
        ->get();
```